# Prove that $(n\mid m$ and $m\mid n) \iff (n=m)$

Tags: number-theory

Prove that $(n\mid m\text{ and }m\mid n) \iff (n=m)$.

**$\rightarrow$**

$n\mid m$ and $m\mid n \rightarrow m=an$ and $n=bm \rightarrow a \geq 1$ and $b \geq 1 \rightarrow m=n$.

**$\leftarrow$**

How do I do this direction?

Comment: The rightward proof only holds for $m, n > 0$.

For the leftward proof, let $a=1$ and $b=1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $m = n$, since $m = 1 \cdot n$, $n \; | \; m$.  By symmetry, $m \; |\; n$ also.

Answer (score 1):

The theorem
$$
( n | m \land m | n ) \iff n = m
$$
isn't actually true. It would be true if the right hand expression was replaced with $n = \pm m$.

If $n=km$, $m=jn$, then $n = kjn \implies 1=kj$.
Because $k,j \in \mathbb{Z}$, this can only be true if either $k = j = 1$ or $k = j = -1$.

Nonetheless, the opposite implication holds:

If $n=m$, then
$$
n = m \cdot 1 \implies m|n \\
m = n \cdot 1 \implies n|m
$$
And amending the theorem with what I stated above we would also need to show the following:

If $n=-m$, then
$$
n = m \cdot -1 \implies m|n \\
m = n \cdot -1 \implies n|m
$$

Answer (score 0):

More generally $a\mid b\implies b=ak$ so that $|b|=|k||a|\geqslant |a|$. Thus $a\mid b$ and $b\mid a$ imply $|a|=|b|$.